# Calling beforeunload ONLY for browser exit - not links or forms etc

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
event.returnValue = `Are you sure you want to leave?`;
});
```

How can I edit it so that it only fires when a user is closing the browser window and not clicking a link or form submit.

I would prefer to edit / add more javascript than have to add anything to my links - as the links change actively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notify user on browser close only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310559/notify-user-on-browser-close-only)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453741/javascript-beforeunload-detect-refresh-versus-close

Comment: And: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291553/is-there-a-way-in-javascript-to-detect-if-the-unload-event-is-caused-via-a-refre/291684#291684

Comment: (Summary: use the search feature)